# Find the inverse image of $\log(x^2+2x+2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

Is there an algebraic way to find the inverse image? The book gives an answer that I think is totally false because it involves the exponential which is wrong because the base of log is not $e$.

the interval is $(0,3]$

thus it should be possible to:

$0 \lt \log(x^2+2x+1) \leq 3$

Taking the log gives:

$1 \lt (x-1)^2 \leq \log(3)$

I run into the same problem for $x^2+1$ $E = (-1,2]$

but algebraically it works for $2-3x$ $E=(-1,2)$

can someone simplify and explain these?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Also, $\log$ is often used for $\ln$.

Comment: What's the question?  Inverse image of what?

Comment: $0\lt\log(x^2+2x+\color{red}1)\le3\implies 1<(x\color{red}+1)^2\le e^3\;$  ($a<b\implies e^a<e^b$)

Answer (score 1):

Many books refer to the operator $\log$ as in base $e$, although I do think that a proper notation is $\ln$, since this label has been specifically designed for the $e$ base. 
In order to find the reverse image in the considered interval you just evolve this inequality 
$$0<\ln{(x^2+2x+2)}<3$$

in this form

$${x^2+2x+2}>1$$
$${x^2+2x+2}<e^3$$

and from now you should be able to proceed further.

Comment: The meaning of “$\log$” varies from field to field. It is generally simply “the logarithm we most commonly use.” In Computer Science, it often denotes logarithm base $2$. In Physics, it is often the natural logarithm. In Calculus textbooks and engineering, it usually denotes the common logarithm (base $10$). It’s not a question of “proper notation”, but of “notational conventions.”

Comment: In calculus I've been thought that this is the only notation, and here we are relating to calculus

Comment: Using log is just brutal and unesthetic in terms of notation. In physics I used ln as well.

Comment: I get down to $-2 \lt (x+1)^2 \lt e^3-3$ after subtracting the two and completing the square

Comment: Should be $\le3$ and $\le e^3$ per OP

Comment: Unesthetic is unaesthetic. Being hit by a log is brutal regardless of base.

Comment: My only point is that “proper” implies judgement; this is just a matter of convention, and as long as people are aware of what the convention is, there is nothing problematic about the use. Formally, we should use $\log_{10}$, not $\log$, for the common logarithm, but we don’t. Why? Because we’ve agreed not to.

Comment: OP wrote $\ln{(x^2+2x+2)}$ not $\ln{(x^2+2x+1)}$

Comment: Re your first sentence: That one specifically designs a notation for a concept doesn't necessarily make that notation advantageous. I wonder how you pronounce $\ln,$ for example.

Comment: Uhm, natural logarithm, or neperian logarithm.